# Casting interface to generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

In my project I have 2 ways to activate an asset. By a path and by a model. Currently the path is working fine but I am having trouble with the model. This is my interface:

```
 public interface IModelConverter<in T> : IConverter where T:IDataCollection
  {
    ResponseData Activate(T documents, ServiceContext services, bool overrideIfNeeded = false);

    bool ContainsFile(T document, ServiceContext services);
  }
```

Now both of those converters (path and model) are under an 'IConverter' interface. People are able to add new converters to a list. Then people can throw a model at the factory and it should look at the T type and check if there is a converter for that specific type. However, I am not able to get that to work.

The problems:

1. I save my converters all under the IConverters interface. I can find the IModelConverters back(with some reflection), but I am not able to parse them to IModelConverter.
2. If I make another IModelConverter interface without the generic (replacing the T with IDataCollection) and having the generic version inherit from that, I have to add 2 methods for both method in the interface I use.

This is currently how check for the models:

```
public Response ActivateFile<T>(T model, ServiceContext services, bool overrideIfNeeded = false) where T : IDataCollection
{
  Response response = new Response();
  List<IModelConverter<IDataCollection>> converterList = modelConverters.Where(x => x.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].Equals(model.GetType())).ToList();

  /*List<IModelConverter<IDataCollection>> converterList = converters
    .Where(x => x.GetType().Equals(typeof(IModelConverter<>)))
    .Where(x => x.GetType().GetInterfaces()
    .Any(z => z.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IModelConverter<>)))
    .Cast<IModelConverter<IDataCollection>>()
    .ToList();*/
  //List<IModelConverter<T>> converterList = modelConverters.Where(x => x is T).ToList();
  //converterList.ForEach(x => response.AddResponseData(x.Activate(model, services, overrideIfNeeded)));
  return response;
}
```

Is there any way I can fix this or should I take a good look at my design again?

Comment: Generic classes are invariant. In other words, if an input parameter specifies a List<BaseClass>, you will get a compile-time error if you try to provide a List<DerivedClass>, [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes)

Comment: `List<IModelConverter<T>> converterList = modelConverters.Where(x => x is IModelConverter<T>).Cast<IModelConverter<T>>().ToList();` But this should work.

Comment: @FilipCordas It gives me an error that the generic T can't be converted to IDataCollection.

Comment: Is this in regards to the second comment or first?

Comment: In regards of your second comment. I have this issue that it can't convert T to the IDataCollection even though it has a where clause and should always be an IDataCollection. Does that have to do with the information of your first comment?

Comment: Well you can't convert `IModelConverter<T>` to `IModelConverter<IDataCollection>` since the two are different classes, and I am not getting any errors for getting the list of `List<IModelConverter<T>>` do you want the list of `List<IModelConverter<IDataCollection>>` as well?

Comment: Can you tell me why the IModelConverter<T> and the IModelConverter<IDataCollection> are different classes? Isn't T atleast an IDataCollection because of the where clause? Making it both the same?

And yeah, you were right. It doesn't give an error when I change the list to T (Forgot to do that). I will see if it that is enough for me to fix it.

Comment: No generic classis don't share an ancestor. When this compiles you will have one class for every type you specify as the generic argument so any T and IDataCollection will generate a different [implementation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6207/Generics-C).

Comment: Ah, I guess I am still missing a lot of knowledge about generics. Another question, hope you don't mind. In the ActivateFile method I have the model and the generic T. However, they are both of 2 different types. The model is of type LanguageCollection (The one that I want) and the other one is of type IDataCollection(Not what I want as nothing is that). Why is that? Shouldn't it both be the same, or is the cause of the where clause?

Comment: I am a bit unclear on what you are asking here. In the collection `modelConverters` you have `IConverter ` but since you can't convert to IModelConverter<> you must use some T type at compile time. You could use reflection to execute on `IConverter` the methods.

Comment: Well, the list isn't returning anything now. I think because there is no instance of IModelConverter<T> where T equals IDataCollection.

Every ModelConverter has it's own model declared in the generic. For example: LanguageConverter has a languagemodel. So we have to search for languagemodel. However, the T isn't languageModel, but IDataCollection. Is that because of the where clause?

Comment: Well the type of T should be the type you called the method with so if you call it with ActivateFile< IDataCollection>( it will use that if you call it with  ActivateFile<LanguageModel> it will be that. Implicit call will be the same it will use the type of what you cast it as.

Comment: I got it working, thanks for the help :)

Comment: try making it into an answer and posting it, if anyone else might have a similar problem.